# Docker - Creating multiple containers/environments with different versions

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm starting with MongoDB and taking four courses. All of them use different versions of mongodb, python, nodejs, asp.net, mean stack, etc. The structure of my desirable workspace:

```
courses
  ├─ mongodb_basic
  │   ├─ hello_world-2.7.py
  │   └─ data
  │       └─ db
  ├─ python-3.6_mongodb
  │   ├─ getting_started.py
  │   └─ data
  │       └─ db
  ├─ dotnet_and_mongodb
  │   ├─ (project files)
  │   └─ data
  │       └─ db
  ├─ mongodb_node
  │   ├─ (project files)
  │   └─ data
  │       └─ db
  └─ mean_intro
      └─ (project files)
```

I want to keep my Windows 10 system clean using Docker without installing all the stuff on the host and stuck in the first course, don't know how to:

- link containers

  - `python/pymongo <-> mongodb`
  - `aspnet <-> mongodb`
  - `... <-> mongodb`
- map data\folders
- start/stop linked containers with one command (desirable)

I'd like to keep a workspace on the host (external HDD) in order to work on different computers (three W10 PCs).

Google results have many tuts (containerize, docker-compose, etc.) and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be possible to do what you are trying to do using docker-compose and defining the *dockerfiles* correctly. So if you are wondering where to start, I would suggest getting acquainted with the [dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/#compose-documentation).

To answer your question:

- **linking containers**:
  that can be done using docker-compose. Specify the container services you want to use in a compose file like the one specified [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-2-create-a-dockerfile).

**NOTE:** the `volumes:` declaration is where you would specify your workspace folder structure for the containers to access.

- **map folder/data:** Again I would check out the link mentioned above. In their `dockerfile` they use the `ADD` command to add the current directory of the container into the path of the `/code` directory. This was included as a `volume:` in the compose file. What does that mean? Well whatever you change in the host workspace, should show up in the root directory of the container.
- **start/stop with one command:** you should be able to create,start or stop all the services or a specific service using one of the `docker-compose up`, `docker-compose start` or `docker-compose stop`
  commands.

For your application you might even be able to get away with defining your workspace as volumes in all of the dockerfiles and then building them with a script. Or you can use some kind of orchestration service like Kubernetes as well but that might be overkill.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @DataDwarf I'll try it.